# How to print High and Low value in this json data?

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "body": {
    "CacheTime": 15,
    "Data": [
      {
        "Exch": "N",
        "ExchType": "C",
        "High": 399.35,
        "LastRate": 393.15,
        "Low": 385.55,
        "PClose": 390.15,
        "TickDt": "/Date(1613298590000+0530)/",
        "Time": 35990,
        "Token": 3045,
        "TotalQty": 0
      }
    ],
    "Message": "Success",
    "Status": 0,
    "TimeStamp": "/Date(1613327845264+0530)/"
  },
  "head": {
    "responseCode": "5PMF",
    "status": "0",
    "statusDescription": "Success"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this is *not* a code writing service, so you need to show your own efforts into solving this and what code you have tried.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66199105/edit) your answer to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO is not a free programming service. That said, do the following:

```
import json

foo = """
    {
      "body": {
        "CacheTime": 15,
        "Data": [
          {
            "Exch": "N",
            "ExchType": "C",
            "High": 399.35,
            "LastRate": 393.15,
            "Low": 385.55,
            "PClose": 390.15,
            "TickDt": "/Date(1613298590000+0530)/",
            "Time": 35990,
            "Token": 3045,
            "TotalQty": 0
          }
        ],
        "Message": "Success",
        "Status": 0,
        "TimeStamp": "/Date(1613327845264+0530)/"
      },
      "head": {
        "responseCode": "5PMF",
        "status": "0",
        "statusDescription": "Success"
      }
    }
"""

bar = json.loads(foo)

print(bar['body']['Data'][0]['High'])  # Prints 399.35
print(bar['body']['Data'][0]['Low'])  # Prints 385.55
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def get_min_max(j_string)
    data = json.loads(j_string)
    return data['body']['Data'][0]['Low'], data['body']['Data'][0]['High']

j = '{ "body": { "CacheTime": 15, "Data": [ { "Exch": "N", "ExchType": "C", "High": 399.35, "LastRate": 393.15, "Low": 385.55, "PClose": 390.15, "TickDt": "/Date(1613298590000+0530)/", "Time": 35990, "Token": 3045, "TotalQty": 0 } ], "Message": "Success", "Status": 0, "TimeStamp": "/Date(1613327845264+0530)/" }, "head": { "responseCode": "5PMF", "status": "0", "statusDescription": "Success" } }'

print(get_min_max(j))
```